# Convert jsonb key value to key value array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

For a note taking application I have the following json document in my PostgreSQL schema right now:

```
postgres=# select id, data from notes where id=107;
 id  |                                           data                                           
-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------    
 107 | {"tag": "sample tag", "title": "sample title", "content": "sample title\n\nsample text"}
```

to be able to use multiple tags in the future I want to convert every existing entry in my database from the above to be in an array like this: `"tag": ["sample tag"]`

I did some research and by playing around I got a bit closer with something like:

```
UPDATE notes SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{tag}', $$["sample tag", "xyz"]$$);
```

which actually updates the row from `"tag": "sample tag"` to `"tag": ["sample tag", "xyz"]` but I want this to run dynamically through all my entries with the existing tags. I couldn't figure out a way to run something like a subquery within the `jsonb_set` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_build_array():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
update notes
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{tag}', jsonb_build_array(data->'tag'));
```

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/FZDYY68370)