# how to associate the row key with each value of a pg jsonb array

Tags: json, postgresql

Suppose we have a Postgres  table

```sql
CREATE TABLE staging_book (
    book_id int4 NULL,
    authors jsonb NULL
);
```

and the value of each authors field is an array of strings.

The first row looks like this.

| work_id | authors |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `["Kafka, Franz", "Feynman, Richard", "Pratchett, Terry"]` |
| 2 | `["Tolkien, JRR", "Tolkien, C"]` |

We are breaking this up into normalised tables and we'd like to put the authors in a separate table.

We'd like to produce this, so we can insert it into a separate table.

| work_id | author |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Kafka, Franz |
| 1 | Feynman, Richard |
| 1 | Pratchett, Terry |
| 2 | Tolkien, JRR |
| 2 | Tolkien, C |

A cross join will not do. This

```sql
SELECT s.work_id, a.author
FROM stagework s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(s.authors) AS a(author);
```

would match every author to every work which is
*obviously* not right and completely fails to address the requirement clearly stated in the title.

This is logically trivial to express with a separate application enumerating the rows and parsing the json, but that would be an inefficient way to process thirty million rows.

I found the `jsonb_array_elements_text` function but I cannot figure out how to match the values with the `work_id` key in a result row. Can this be done directly in SQL?

This seems related [Convert jsonb key value to key value array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016987)

I am well aware there is a many to many relationship between authors and works. There's also a lot of borked data to fix before I start removing the redundancy.

Comment: Yes.  It can be done.  Use a `cross join lateral` to `jsonb_array_elements_text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This [CROSS JOIN LATERAL] would match every author to every work which is obviously not right and completely fails to address the requirement clearly stated in the title.

Nope. It does exactly what you want. Notice the [`LATERAL` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) - it means the function is executed for each individual row of the left relation, and only joined against that.

[Try it!](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sz8pNe_7)

Comment: For table functions like `jsonb_array_elements_text`, the `LATERAL` keyword is in fact optional, [it works even without](https://dbfiddle.uk/MCeB5aZ_)